# Ошибки при комментировании и создании вопросов

Tags: поддержка

Регулярно получаю сообщение "Во время комментария произошла ошибка" при попытке отправить комментарий и "Во время вопроса произошла ошибка" при создании нового. С чем это может быть связано? 
С комментариями ошибка возникает в хроме, а в мозиле нормально отправляются. При создании вопроса - ошибка возникает и там и там.

При этом свой первый вопрос, успешно создал и даже пару раз ответил в комментариях и дополнил тело вопроса (все это в хроме), затем началось вот такое.

upd. Удалил ссылку на har. почитал что не безопасно это. Опытным путем установил что любой комментарий отправляется, вопрос постится если просто постучать по enter раз 20-30. С чем связаны "капризы" сервера что он не хочет сразу обрабатывать - непонятно

Comment: Попробуйте открыть консоль разработчика и воспроизвести. Сохраните параметры отправляемого POST-запроса и полученный ответ, добавьте их к вопросу.

Comment: @NickVolynkin готово.

Comment: У меня наоборот в ФФ отправка частенько глючит. :( Причём в логах запросов отображается только дырка от бублика, будто соединения и не было вовсе. Если долго тыкать на отправку, то в конце концов срабатывает.

Comment: @Squidward вот у меня кажется нечто похожее. Я случайно enter зажал когда на свой вопрос комментарий писал на самом SO и оно через зажатие отправилось, судя по POST'у, у меня та же история, как будто соединения и не было.

Comment: У меня в FF такое бывает примерно раз в неделю при нажатии на кнопку upvote. После обновления страницы и повторного нажатия всегда отправляется нормально. Поскольку со - весьма нагруженный сайт, то считаю, что такое редкое поведение вполне простительно. Сидеть на со постоянно с включенной панелью разработчика мне лень.

Comment: Что за файл с расширением .har?

Comment: @NickVolynkin сохраненные даннные из консоли. Открывается через https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/

Answer (score 1):

Проанализировать как-либо ситуацию можно лишь имея логи. Сугубо из своей практики могу сказать, что подобные ошибки возникают в 99% случаев из–за проблем с сетью. Пожалуйста, в случае повторения ошибки, снимите логи из консоли разработчика, и убедитесь, что с соединением нет проблем.